# Как определить день и месяц следующего понедельника?

Tags: javascript

На странице нужно выводить дату следующего понедельника. Например. если заходим на страницу сегодня, то выводится "13 февраля". Также если мы зайдем на страницу до 7 вечера 13 февраля, то дата не меняется. Но если мы заходим 13 февраля после 7 часов вечера, выводится уже 20 февраля, и т.д. Как это можно реализовать? Код написать не могу, т.к. даже не представляю, с чего начать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var d = new Date();
var monthNames = new Array("Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь");

//допустим сегодня 13 текущего месяца
d.setDate(13);

var currentHour = d.getHours(); // 18 для проверки

if(currentHour < 19) {
  // до 19:00, показываем текущий понедельник
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + (1 + 7 - d.getDay()) % 7);
} else {
  //после 19:00, показываем следующий понедельник
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + (7-d.getDay())%7+1);
}

alert(d.getDate() + ' - ' + monthNames[d.getMonth()]);
```

Comment: Можете дать короткий комментарий по скрипту? Хотелось бы понять, как работает :-)

Comment: Я если на компьютере меняю дату на 13 февраля. и у меня сейчас время 20:26, но все-равно дату выводит 13 февраля. И не могу понять, как тут редактировать время (7 вечера).

Comment: добавил проверку времени, вроде работает, а формулы первые попавшиеся в инте.

Comment: Блин, как же в этом разобраться :-) Это d.setDate(13); для чего используется?

Comment: А если сегодня не 13?

Comment: `setDate(13)` добавил просто для теста, вместо этого вы будете использовать текушую дату `new Date();`

Comment: Тут нужно как-то передать в setDate часы, чтобы условия не использовать. Чтобы сутки считались, например, с 19 часов до 19 часов.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать библиотеку момент. 
Следующий понедельник будет:

```
moment().day(8).format('DD.MM.YYYY')
```

метод day выбирает день относительно установленого числа. Например,

```
moment().day(1).format('DD')
```

покажет дату для понедельника который на этой неделе.